# R regression model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to do a regression analysis in R however, I have variables that are qualitative for example(1=Restaurant, 2=Phone). I changed them using the function factor but, I need to separate the values in order to have two different variables for my regression analysis. How can I do this?

Comment: You don't. R is clever and will compare each level of your factor when put into a model. E.g.: `y <- rnorm(100); x <- sample(factor(c("a","b","c")), 100, replace=TRUE); lm(y ~ x)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data is in a dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,1,1,1,2), var2 = c("IceCream", "Batman", "IceCream", "Batman",  "Batman"))
```

Then we can use the `subset` function:

```
subset(dat, var1 == 1)
subset(dat, var1 == 2)
```

another way:

```
dat[dat$var1==1,]
```

another way:

```
dat_split <- split(dat, dat$var1)
dat_split$`1`
```

There are a million ways to subset in `R`.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question. From what I understood the issue is with fitting a linear model including categorical predictor variables.

Comment: It's a badly worded question for sure. I understood it as trying to separate factors in a R *for regression analysis*.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `model.matrix`. Using the example by @thelatemail above:

```
y <- rnorm(100) 
x <- sample(factor(c("a","b","c")), 100, replace=TRUE)
head(x)
[1] a b a c a c
Levels: a b c

x1 <- model.matrix(~x-1)
head(x1)
  xa xb xc
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  1
5  0  1  0
6  0  1  0
```

Note that the `-1` part, means that there's no intercept in the model matrix. Be careful when you use that in your regression!

In practice, you should follow @thelatemail's advice and just run `lm(y~x)`! I'm just giving you a way of creating the new variables you want.